# How can I use both a key and an index for the same dictionary value?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I need an array of data that has a numeric index, but also a human readable index. I need the latter because the numeric indices may change in the future, and I need the numeric indices as a part of a fixed length socket message.

My imagination suggests something like this:

```
ACTIONS = {
    (0, "ALIVE") : (1, 4, False),
    (2, "DEAD") : (2, 1, True)
}

>ACTIONS[0]
(1, 4, False)
>ACTIONS["DEAD"]
(2, 1, True)
```

Comment: Awesome question! I would suggest that you change the title of the question to "Multiple Keys per Dictionary Value" to help others wondering the same thing to find this.

Comment: the accepted answer do not match the title of the question (though it is right for this problem)...

Comment: He can access values in a dict both by keys and by numerical indexes - that's pretty much what I was after. I should change the title

Comment: @d.putto: I changed the title - please edit it if you feel it can be better

Comment: @Codemonkey I have created another question with the title 'multiple-keys-per-value' http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11449232/multiple-keys-per-value Please edit my question to make it more to the topic. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use Python 2.7's collections.OrderedDict

```
In [23]: d = collections.OrderedDict([
   ....:   ("ALIVE", (1, 4, False)),
   ....:   ("DEAD", (2, 1, True)),
   ....: ])

In [25]: d["ALIVE"]
Out[25]: (1, 4, False)

In [26]: d.values()[0]
Out[26]: (1, 4, False)

In [27]: d.values()[1]
Out[27]: (2, 1, True)
```

Comment: This turned out to be a great solution! At first I assumed `OrderedDict` meant a dictionary that would order itself automatically, not a dictionary that let me decide the order. Anyway, thanks :-)

Answer (score 7):

The simplest way to achieve this is to have *two* dictionaries:  One mapping the indices to your values, and one mapping the string keys to the same objects:

```
>> actions = {"alive": (1, 4, False), "dead": (2, 1, True)}
>> indexed_actions = {0: actions["alive"], 2: actions["dead"]}
>> actions["alive"]
(1, 4, False)
>> indexed_actions[0]
(1, 4, False)
```

Comment: This has a bit of a gotcha, though: indexed_actions and actions aren't kept in sync if you change one of the keys to a new value, even though actions["alive"] is indexed_actions[0].

Comment: I have similar issue and I am using this method. Is there any other way ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to name your keys for code readability, you can do the following:

```
ONE, TWO, THREE  = 1, 2, 3

ACTIONS = {
    ONE : value1,
    TWO : value2
}
```

Comment: The problem is to make something like `ACTIONS[DEAD]` possible.

Answer (score 1):

Namedtuples are nice:

```
>>> import collections
>>> MyTuple = collections.namedtuple('MyTuple', ('x','y','z'))
>>> t = MyTuple(1,2,3)
>>> t
MyTuple(x=1, y=2, z=3)
>>> t[0]
1
>>> t.x
1
>>> t.y
2
```

Comment: I think I get what you're saying, but I didn't at first. You should spell it out; an upvote is waiting for you if you do. If the OP doesn't need _strings_, but only a human-readable way to represent numerical key values, then this is an excellent solution IMO.

Comment: The OP didn't really asked for a string representation... Anyway, he also could do `t._asdict()['x']` and achieve that