# Multiple keys per value

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Is it possible to assign multiple keys per value in a Python dictionary. One possible solution is to assign value to each key:

```
dict = {'k1':'v1', 'k2':'v1', 'k3':'v1', 'k4':'v2'}
```

but this is not memory efficient since my data file is > 2 GB. Otherwise you could make a dictionary of dictionary keys:

```
key_dic = {'k1':'k1', 'k2':'k1', 'k3':'k1', 'k4':'k4'}
dict = {'k1':'v1', 'k4':'v2'}
main_key = key_dict['k2']
value = dict[main_key]
```

This is also very time and effort consuming because I have to go through whole dictionary/file twice. Is there any other easy and inbuilt Python solution?

Note: my dictionary values are not simple string (as in the question 'v1', 'v2') rather complex objects (contains different other dictionary/list etc. and not possible to pickle them) 
Note: the question seems similar as [How can I use both a key and an index for the same dictionary value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6164973/how-can-i-use-both-a-key-and-an-index-for-the-same-dictionary-value#comment15078538_6164973)
 But I am not looking for ordered/indexed dictionary and I am looking for other efficient solutions (if any) other then the two mentioned in this question.

Comment: You are unlikely to find a solution better than your first one.  Just put multiple keys in the dictionary.  Why is this not good enough?

Comment: As I said in question the file is very large so putting same values multiple time need lot of memory.

Comment: Values in python are not necessarily duplicated in python, even if using multiple keys to refer to them.

Comment: The value won't use up extra memory unless you recreate it every time.  See the answer from  @Useless.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - oh I missed this point I think I should do more test  now I remember i,j=0, 0; id(i)==id(j); True :)

Comment: this is were pointers would come in handy ... _explicit is better than implicit_

Comment: @moooeeeep Heavens, no. That reflects a fundamental misunderstanding of the Python object model. You expect things to work this way because they always work this way. Python *does* reflect "explicit is better than implicit" - by expecting you to be explicit when you want the *other* semantics (i.e. value semantics). You do this e.g. by using the `copy` module, or by otherwise writing code that forces creation of a new object with the same value.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I am used to have a higher degree of explicitness imposed by the language itself. I mean, Python implicitly uses the pointer-like object reference model.

Comment: @moooeeeep that's nonsense. You have to choose an object model. C++ just-as-"implicitly" uses the value object model.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel it requires you to specify the exact type value/pointer/reference every time you want to use an object. Couldn't be more explicit, I think.

Comment: @moooeeeep that's a **completely** different issue. Manifest typing has absolutely nothing to do with value vs. reference semantics, and anyway isn't "explicit" in a sense that Pythonistas consider remotely meaningful.

Answer (score 38):

What type are the values?

```
dict = {'k1':MyClass(1), 'k2':MyClass(1)}
```

will give duplicate value objects, but

```
v1 = MyClass(1)
dict = {'k1':v1, 'k2':v1}
```

results in both keys referring to the same actual object.

In the original question, your values are strings: even though you're declaring the same string twice, I think they'll be interned to the same object in that case

---

NB. if you're not sure whether you've ended up with duplicates, you can find out like so:

```
if dict['k1'] is dict['k2']:
    print("good: k1 and k2 refer to the same instance")
else:
    print("bad: k1 and k2 refer to different instances")
```

(`is` check thanks to J.F.Sebastian, replacing `id()`)

Comment: dictionary values are not simple string rather complex object (contains different other dictionary/list etc.)

Comment: you could use `obj1 is obj2` to test object identity instead of `id(obj1) == id(obj2)`

Comment: @d.putto - in that case make sure you're storing the same _instance_ with each key, not a duplicate instance with the same contents (as per my first two examples).  If unsure, confirm with `is`

Comment: type doesn't matter. You shouldn't rely on how Python treats some immutable objects. If you need the same object; just provide it (as in `v1` example)

Comment: I agree you _shouldn't_, just wanted to check whether the OP was already getting automagical interning.  Thanks for the `is` reminder btw.

Comment: And here's the relevant page in the documentation: http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#objects-values-and-types

Answer (score 12):

Check out this - it's an implementation of exactly what you're asking: multi_key_dict(ionary)

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/multi_key_dict
(sources at https://github.com/formiaczek/python_data_structures/tree/master/multi_key_dict)

(on Unix platforms it possibly comes as a package and you can try to install it with something like:

```
sudo apt-get install python-multi-key-dict
```

for Debian, or an equivalent for your distribution)

You can use different types for keys but also keys of the same type. Also you can iterate over items using key types of your choice, e.g.:

```
m = multi_key_dict()
m['aa', 12] = 12
m['bb', 1] = 'cc and 1'
m['cc', 13] = 'something else'

print m['aa']   # will print '12'
print m[12]     # will also print '12'

# but also:
for key, value in m.iteritems(int):
    print key, ':', value
# will print:1
# 1 : cc and 1
# 12 : 12
# 13 : something else

# and iterating by string keys:
for key, value in m.iteritems(str):
    print key, ':', value
# will print:
# aa : 12
# cc : something else
# bb : cc and 1

m[12] = 20 # now update the value
print m[12]   # will print '20' (updated value)
print m['aa']   # will also print '20' (it maps to the same element)
```

There is no limit to number of keys, so code like:

```
m['a', 3, 5, 'bb', 33] = 'something'
```

is valid, and either of keys can be used to refer to so-created value (either to read / write or delete it).

Edit: From version 2.0 it should also work with python3.

Comment: What about the case when two keys contain the same element, say `m['aa', 12]` and `m[12, 'bb']`. What happens when you do `m[12] = 20`

Comment: if two keys contain the same element (which is actually what this is trying to achieve) - this element can be accessed with either of those keys, and removal of either (e.g. `del[12]` or `del['aa']`) will remove the element and it won't be accessible by any other key (also references to this other key(s) are removed).

Comment: `m[12] = 20` will either: 1) if m doesn't contain element with this key (single or multiple) - it will create an element with key 12 and assign (map) it to the value 20 (like standard dictionary). 2) If element exists (like in example above) it will update the value referenced by this key. If this value was mapped with multiple keys - accessing it with these other keys will refer to this (updated) value. I have updated example above to reflect this.

Comment: I tried to run it through 2to3.py, but things go south in the tests when I first hit __setitem__. I'm not sure what is causing it, but it ends up calling __getitem__ recursively and eventually exceeds the maximum recursion depth. Unfortunately because it sounds like this dictionary type might be what I need to use for the problem I'm trying to solve.

Answer (score 3):

The most straightforward way to do this is to construct your dictionary using the dict.fromkeys() method. It takes a sequence of keys and a value as inputs and then assigns the value to each key.
Your code would be:

```
dict = dict.fromkeys(['k1', 'k2', 'k3'], 'v1')
dict.update(dict.fromkeys(['k4'], 'v2'))
```

And the output is:

```
print(dict)
{'k1': 'v1', 'k2': 'v1', 'k3': 'v1', 'k4': 'v2'}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using python 2.7/3 you can combine a tuple, value pair with dictionary comprehension.

```
keys_values = ( (('k1','k2'), 0), (('k3','k4','k5'), 1) )

d = { key : value for keys, value in keys_values for key in keys }
```

You can also update the dictionary similarly.

```
keys_values = ( (('k1',), int), (('k3','k4','k6'), int) )

d.update({ key : value for keys, value in keys_values for key in keys })
```

I don't think this really gets to the heart of your question but in light of the title, I think this belongs here.

Comment: I've found your post in a review. I don't understand this topic enough to judge your answer, so I'm skipping this review, leaving it to others. Anyway, let me say that an answer that says "I don't think this really gets to the heart of your question" doesn't look like a good one to me. The fact that you are addressing the title is not enough. Then again, as I said I don't understand enough of this topic, so I am not going to vote in any way. But I still suggest to improve this answer so that you don't have to write "I don't think this really gets to the heart of your question".

Comment: Sorry for the confusion Fabio, though I think we might have a semantic disagreement about what it means to be the heart of a matter. I think my solution is suitable for assigning multiple keys to a common value and this is indeed the question as it is posed in the title and the first part of d.putto's post. The second requirement, to be  'memory efficient' is what I considered the heart of the question. I hope this helps to validate my response. Nevertheless I feel like your comment addresses neither the original post nor the heart of my response and is therefore irrelevant to the discussion.

Answer (score 1):

You can build an auxiliary dictionary of objects that were already created from the parsed data. The key would be the parsed data, the value would be your constructed object -- say the string value should be converted to some specific object. This way you can control when to construct the new object:

```
existing = {}   # auxiliary dictionary for making the duplicates shared
result = {}
for k, v in parsed_data_generator():
    obj = existing.setdefault(v, MyClass(v))  # could be made more efficient
    result[k] = obj
```

Then all the `result` dictionary duplicate value objects will be represented by a single object of the `MyClass` class. After building the result, the `existing` auxiliary dictionary can be deleted.

Here the `dict.setdefault()` may be elegant and brief. But you should test later whether the more talkative solution is not more efficient -- see below. The reason is that `MyClass(v)` is always created (in the above example) and then thrown away if its duplicate exists:

```
existing = {}   # auxiliary dictionary for making the duplicates shared
result = {}
for k, v in parsed_data_generator():
    if v in existing:
        obj = existing[v]
    else:
        obj = MyClass(v)
        existing[v] = obj

    result[k] = obj
```

This technique can be used also when `v` is not converted to anything special. For example, if `v` is a string, both key and value in the auxiliary dictionary will be of the same value. However, the existence of the dictionary ensures that the object will be shared (which is not always ensured by Python).

Answer (score 1):

I was able to achieve similar functionality using pandas [MultiIndex](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html), although in my case the values are scalars:

```
>>> import numpy
>>> import pandas
>>> keys = [numpy.array(['a', 'b', 'c']), numpy.array([1, 2, 3])]
>>> df = pandas.DataFrame(['val1', 'val2', 'val3'], index=keys)
>>> df.index.names = ['str', 'int']
>>> df.xs('b', axis=0, level='str')
        0
int      
2    val2

>>> df.xs(3, axis=0, level='int')
        0
str      
c    val3
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised no one has mentioned using Tuples with dictionaries. This works just fine:

```
my_dictionary = {}
my_dictionary[('k1', 'k2', 'k3')] = 'v1'
my_dictionary[('k4')] = 'v2'
```

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't solve the problem, since you can't call my_dictionary['k1'] to get 'v1' (you'll get KeyError, since the right key for that value is ('k1', 'k2', 'k3'))