# multiple keys in python dictionary, is possible?

Tags: python, dictionary, key

I'd like to build a dictionary in python in which different keys refer to the same element. I have this dictionary:

```
persons = {"George":'G.MacDonald', "Luke":'G.MacDonald', "Larry":'G.MacDonald'}
```

the key refer all to an identical string but the strings have different memory location inside the program, I'd like to make a dictionary in which all these keys refer to the same element, is that possible?

Comment: Are you saying whenever you create a string it will use one in memory?

Comment: Anyway when you construct the dictionary, they are all the exact same string. What application is this for?

Comment: `foo = 'G.MacDonald'; persons = {'George': foo, 'Luke': foo, 'Larry': foo}`

Comment: Perhaps a multi-key dictionary implementation could solve this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11449232/multiple-keys-per-value/16966988#16966988

Comment: **See also:** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47524648/get-value-from-dictionary-for-first-key-that-exists

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
import itertools as it

unique_dict = {}
value_key=lambda x: x[1]
sorted_items = sorted(your_current_dict.items(), key=value_key)
for value, group in it.groupby(sorted_items, key=value_key):
    for key in group:
        unique_dict[key] = value
```

This transforms your dictionary into a dictionary where equal values of any kind(but comparable) are unique. If your values are not comparable(but are hashable) you could use a temporary `dict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict
unique_dict = {}
tmp_dict = defaultdict(list)

for key, value in your_current_dict.items():
    tmp_dict[value].append(key)

for value, keys in tmp_dict.items():
    unique_dict.update(zip(keys, [value] * len(keys)))
```

Answer (score 2):

If you happen to be using python 3, `sys.intern` offers a very elegant solution:

```
for k in persons:
    persons[k] = sys.intern(persons[k])
```

In Python 2.7, you can do roughly the same thing with one extra step:

```
interned = { v:v for v in set(persons.itervalues()) }
for k in persons:
    persons[k] = interned[persons[k]]
```

In 2.x (< 2.7), you can write `interned = dict( (v, v) for … )` instead.