# Update values for multiple keys in python

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples

What is the cleanest way to update the values of multiple keys in a dictionary to the values stored in a tuple?

Example:

I want to go from

```
>>>mydict = {'a':None, 'b':None, 'c':None, 'd':None}
>>>mytuple = ('alpha', 'beta', 'delta')
```

to

```
>>>print mydict
{'a':'alpha', 'b':'beta', 'c':None, 'd':'delta'}
```

Is there an easy one-liner for this?  Something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209840/map-two-lists-into-a-dictionary-in-python) seems to be getting close to what I want.

EDIT:
I don't wish to assign values to keys based on their first letter. I'm just hoping for something like

```
mydict('a','b','d') = mytuple
```

Obviously that doesn't work, but I'm hoping for something similar to that.

Comment: What rule are you using in your head to associate the value `alpha` with the key `a`? That the value starts with `a`?

Comment: Check this link: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16129405/multiple-keys-in-python-dictionary-is-possible][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16129405/multiple-keys-in-python-dictionary-is-possible

Comment: @ipinak: I don't see the relevance

Comment: Eric, apologies for not being clear in my original question. I've updated it to reflect what I want.

Comment: @eric the first answer of that post gives the answer to the requested problem. It's indirect somehow, but still the answer is there as well. I didn't say it's a duplicate, I just forward to that post. So, I believe it is relevant.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're trying to create a new dictionary:

```
d = dict(zip(keys, valuetuple))
```

If you're trying to add to an existing one, just change the `=` to `.update(…)`.

So, your example can be written as:

```
mydict.update(dict(zip('abd', mytuple))))
```

If you're doing this more than once, I'd wrap it up in a function, so you can write:

```
setitems(d, ('a', 'b', 'd'), mytuple)
```

Or maybe a "curried" function that parallels operator.itemgetter?

Comment: This works! mydict.update(dict(zip(['a','b','d'],mytuple))) worked wonders!

Comment: @nfazzio: I just realized I used 'abd' as shorthand for your ['a', 'b', 'd']. That will work (since a string is a sequence of 1-character strings), but I think your way is clearer.

Answer (score 0):

You could use list comprehension to make it a one-liner, though it's not super efficient.

```
keys = [ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
values = ['alpha', 'beta', 'delta']
dictionary = dict([(k,v) for k in keys for v in values if v.startswith(k)])
print dictionary #prints {'a': 'alpha', 'b': 'beta', 'd': 'delta'}
```

Comment: Justin, this isn't quite what I want. I want to update existing keys in a dictionary with values from a tuple. Thanks for the extra startswith method, but it's unnecessary - I've updated my question to reflect that it isn't necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the association key <-> value is the first letter of the value is the first letter of the key.

```
dict( (v[0],v) for v in mytuple if v[0] in mydict)
```

Comment: This kind of thing can be written slightly more neatly with a dictionary comprehension: `{v[0]: v for v in mytuple if v[0] in mydict}`

Comment: This misses the `c` key. The result would be `{'a': 'alpha', 'b': 'beta', 'd': 'delta'}`

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid one-liners in this case. It makes code more readable.

```
for t in mytuple:
    if t[0] in mydict.keys():
        mydict[t[0]] = t
```

If you want to add mytuple items even if the key does not exist, simply remove the `if` statement.