# Get value from dictionary for first key that exists

Tags: python, dictionary, lookup

### TL;DR

Is there a Python dictionary method or simple expression that returns a value for the first key (from a list of possible keys) that exists in a dictionary?

### Details

Lets say I have a Python dictionary with a number of key-value pairs. The existence of any particular key not guaranteed.

```
d = {'A':1, 'B':2, 'D':4}
```

If I want to get a value for a given key, and return some other default value (e.g. `None`) if that key doesn't exist, I simply do:

```
my_value = d.get('C', None) # Returns None
```

But what if I want to check a number of possible keys before defaulting to a final default value? One way would be:

```
my_value = d.get('C', d.get('E', d.get('B', None))) # Returns 2
```

but this gets rather convoluted as the number of alternate keys increases.

Is there a Python function that exists for this scenario? I imagine something like:

```
d.get_from_first_key_that_exists(('C', 'E', 'B'), None) # Should return 2
```

If such a method doesn't exist, is there a simple expression that is commonly used in such a scenario?

Comment: write your expected output

Comment: @sachindubey Added my expected output.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using a plain old for loop, the flow control is clearest:

```
for k in 'CEB':
    try:
        v = d[k]
    except KeyError:
        pass
    else:
        break
else:
    v = None
```

If you want to one-liner it, that's possible with a comprehension-like syntax:

```
v = next((d[k] for k in 'CEB' if k in d), None)
```

Comment: Nice! The `for` loop is definitely more explicit, but I really like the comprehension example, especially with the use of `next`.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing exists.

```
x = ["1", "3"]
d = {'1': 1, '2': 2, '3': 3}
d[[k for k in x if x in d][0]]
```

Just use a list comprehension.

Edit: Bonus Points:

```
all_matches = [d[k] for k in x if x in d]
all_matches[0]
```

if you'd like all possible keys (poor efficiency if you don't)

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this

```
dict_keys=yourdict.keys()
expected_keys=['a','b','c']

result= list(set(dict_keys).intersection(set(expected_keys)))
if result:
    for i in expected_keys:
        if i in result:
            yourdict.get(i)
```

Comment: edited the code

Comment: This is probably better than mine, you beat me to it. Ideally we could do away with needing if indentation via some other safe means.

Comment: This will use one possible key, but won't necessarily use the first key that exists (sets are not ordered).

Comment: I have edited my code, now it will get the value for first key in expected keys

Comment: This method can be inefficient if the data is large (it must find all of the intersecting keys first, even though only one is needed).