# Get elements of a tuple-indexed dictionary specifying only one field of the tuple

Tags: python, list

I've got a big (20k+) set of data in a form of a dictionary indexed by tuple, e.g.

```
a = {(1,'000200','l1p'): 53, (15,'230512','l3c'): 81, ...}
```

I would like to filter that dictionary providing only one field of that tuple, e.g.

```
a[(_,_,'l1p')]`, or `a[(:,:,'l1p')]
```

Is there any better way than creating a list, like

```
[i for i in a.keys() if 'l1p' in i]
```

As I said, I'm trying to avoid copying elements as there are many entries in the dictionary.

EDIT: Is there any other way of obtaining the elements with 'l1p' in the key-tuple than iterating over the whole dictionary? I would like to perform a recursive least-square fitting on resultant sub-list.

Comment: How are you going to use the new list?

Comment: That looks a lot more like a dictionary than a list.

Comment: Are the keys still unique with just one field of the tuple?

Comment: See the Multi-key dictionary answer for this question:
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11449232/multiple-keys-per-value/11449344#11449344

Comment: dansalmo: I'm going to perform some arithmetic operations on the new list. The entries will not be unique after removing any of the tuple fields at filtering stage, i.e. all three fields provided in tuple are necessary to identify the value. After applying the 'l1p' filter I don't need the values to be ordered any more. I need just the values with 'l1p' key. 
DSM: yea, my bad. I ment a dictionary of course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, what you have is a dictionary, not a list (and *definitely* not a tuple).  Lists and tuples are just sequences of values numbered 0, 1, 2, ..., etc., while a dictionary is an unordered set of values each labelled & accessed with a unique key (in this case, the tuples).

With that out of the way, to get all of the values of `a` where the third element of the key is `'l1p'`, you can just do:

```
[v for k,v in a.items() if k[2] == 'l1p']
```

If you're concerned about saving memory and won't be trying to evaluate the entire result at once, this can be rewritten as a generator expression:

```
(v for k,v in a.items() if k[2] == 'l1p')
```

Note that, if you're using Python 2, `a.items()` will need to be changed to `a.iteritems()`, or the change to a generator will have been for naught.

Alternatively, if you want to instead get a sub-dictionary that includes the matching keys, do:

```
{k: v for k,v in a.items() if k[2] == 'l1p'}
```

Note that this is not a memory-friendly option.  The closest analogue using a generator would be to create a generator of `(key, value)` pairs rather than a proper dictionary:

```
((k,v) for k,v in a.items() if k[2] == 'l1p')
```

Comment: regarding the tuple in the question: that edit was a little bit late at night, too late I see, sorry for that. 

Thanks for the answer, I didn't think about a sub-dictionary. However, I don't need an ordered list after I filter it. As  I mentioned in question comment I only need the values that meed the 'l1p' filter. Therefore, my question was rather: 

Can you get those elements in other way that iterating over whole dictionary?

Comment: @SebastianKramer: No, you cannot.